# Send items from forloop populated data in django template through ajax to django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, django

I have been trying to create a click and populate div with ajax in my django e-commerce application. The project works in such a way that when a customer clicks on a category in men's page it populates another div

### gender.html

```
{%for cate in cat%}
<a href="javascript:getcat()" id="catgend" cats-data="{{cate.catname}}" gen-data="{{gens.gender}}" data-sort-url="{% url 'Home:sortcat' cpk=cate.pk %}" >{{cate.catname}}</a>
{% endfor %}
<div id="products">
  <div class="progress">
      <img src="{% static 'img/load.gif'%}">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

This sends the data to my django view through the ajax function called getcat but the data sent through is that of the first item in the loop in-respective of the loop item clicked on. below is my ajax function:

### getcat()

```js
function getcat() {
    $(".progress").show()
    var cat = $("#catgend").attr("cats-data");
    var gender = $("#catgend").attr("gen-data");
    var url = $("#catgend").attr("data-sort-url");
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: {
            'cat': cat,
            'gender': gender,
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#products").html(data);
        }
    });
    $(".progress").hide()
}
```

```
enter code here
```

From my research i discovered its because they have same ID. How do i solve the issue of dynamically changing the id over the same loop. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the `id` attribute with a `class` attribute since you shouldn't have more than a single element with the same `id`. Also, we can change `cats-data` and `gen-data` to valid `data-*` attributes.

```
{% for cate in cat %}
  <a href="#" class="catgend" data-cats="{{cate.catname}}" data-gen="{{gens.gender}}" data-sort-url="{% url 'Home:sortcat' cpk=cate.pk %}" >{{cate.catname}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Bind a click event to anchors using the new class name.

```
$('.catgend').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.progress').show()
    var data = $(this).data()
    $.ajax({                       
        url: data.sortUrl,                    
        data: {
            'cat': data.cats,
            'gender': data.gen,     
        },
        success: function (data) {   
            $('#products').html(data);  
        }
    });
    $('.progress').hide()
});
```

Utilise the data attributes to accumulate data values in a simple way.